# Progress from Web API Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET web form where user can choose some mailing list and send email to all members of this list by clicking Send button. On click I make ajax call to ASP.NET Web API method, that synchronously sends email to each addressee with some interval between sendings using SmtpClient. This may take a long time and I want my user to see some progress, for example after each sending.

How can I fire progress event to client from web API method? All examples I found were about uploading/downloading files.

Comment: In order to show your client a progress you should either poll for it or get it pushed over e.g. a websocket connection

Answer (score 2):

Use an asynchronous method to send the emails. Implement a method that can be polled to get the current status.